# How to get the previous and following word of another word in a text?

Tags: php, text

I have a HTML formatted text and an array with some words. Something like this:

```
$text = '<h1>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</hi><p>consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed eu leo magna. Curabitur <b>fermentum dapibus</b> nulla fermentum ultrices.</br> Duis <i>in</i> magna quam. Proin laoreet lorem vitae tortor tempus dictum. Morbi.</p>';

$words = array('elit', 'ultrices', 'in', 'house');
```

Now, I want to check if the elements in `$words` exists in `$text` and, if it exists, I want to get an array with a substring of three words (with the element searched in the middle) for each element in `$words` exists in `$text`. Something like this:

```
$array_words[0] = 'adipiscing elit. Sed';
$array_words[1] = 'fermentum ultrices. Duis';
$array_words[2] = 'Duis in magna';
```

I know how to search a word, but I don't know any easy way to get the previous and following word in the text.

Comment: Split by whitespace, lookup word, then look at index n-1, n+1 ?

Comment: Everyone now has opened texteditor and hacking the solution as fast as possible

Comment: What's happening if you look for a word that exist many times in the text?

Comment: @zeflex for every match, it has to be an element in `$array_words`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give this a go:

```
function getwords($text, $words){
    $r = array();
    $text = strip_tags($text);
    foreach($words as $word){
        preg_match_all('/(\w+\W+|^)' . $word . '(\W+\w+|$)/',$text,$m);

        foreach ( $m[0] as $match ){
            if ( !empty($match) )
                array_push($r,$match);
        }
    }
    return $r;
}

$text = 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</hi><p>consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed eu leo magna. Curabitur <b>fermentum dapibus</b> nulla fermentum    ultrices.</br> Duis <i>in</i> magna quam. Proin  laoreet lorem vitae tortor tempus dictum. Morbi.</p> Lorem';
$words = array('elit', 'ultrices', 'in', 'Lorem');
print_r(getwords($text, $words));
```

Result:

```
Array
(
    [0] => adipiscing elit. Sed
    [1] => fermentum    ultrices. Duis
    [2] => Duis in magna
    [3] => Lorem ipsum
    [4] => Morbi. Lorem
)
```

Should also handle case of matches on first or last word as demonstrated with the "Lorem" string.

I wasn't sure what your results should show if the word shows up twice so I just returned all instances of the word.

Comment: That's what I'm asking for, now I have to change the regular expression to get what I actually want.

Answer (score 0):

```
//remove HTML tags
$text = strip_tags($text);

//replace double spaces, newline and tab with single space
$text = preg_replace('/\s+/', ' ',$text);

//split string in array of words
$p = explode (' ', $text);
```

...and now use array index to check the previous and the next element

Comment: Your solutions fails with the case of the word `elit` because in the `$text` it has a "." (dot). It has to match "elit.", "elit,", "elit!", etc.

Answer (score 0):

You can explode your string with space

```
$arr=explode(" ",$text);
$final_arr=array();
foreach($words as $key=>$value)
{
$key = array_search($value, $arr);
 if($key)
 {
    $final_arr[]=$arr[$key-1].$arr[$key].$arr[$key+1];
 }
}
```

Comment: Your solutions fails with the case of the word `elit` because in the `$text` it has a "." (dot). It has to match "elit.", "elit,", "elit!", etc.